# How to repeat a line thrice in Perl after searching a string

Tags: string, perl

```
.march_endSP(march_end),

.serial_in_ctlr(serial_in_ctlr) ,
.memsafe(memsafe) ,
.mem_atpg_mode(mem_atpg_mode) ,
.tst_gatedclock(tst_gatedclock) ,
```

I want to search a string `.march_endSP`  in a file and repeat that line with

```
.march_endSP_1(march_end)
.march_endSP_2(march_end)
.march_endSP_3(march_end)
```

in the same file, how can I do this?

This is my code

```
while (my $line = <FH>) {
  while ( $line =~ /-number_of_SP_mem_supp\s(\d+)/g ) {
   my $first = $1;
   #print "$first\n";
   my @a = (1..$first);
   foreach(@a){
    print("$_","\n");
}
  }
```

But I am unable to do using this.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
if (my ($tail) = $line =~ /^\.march_endSP)(.*)/) {
   print(".march_endSP_$_$tail\n") for 1..3;
} else {
   print($line);
}
```